# Spring boot elastic not giving expected result

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot

I am querying elastic through spring boot.

case:- 1

There is some data in my elastic like region = "REGION 1"

I want to get all the data where "REGION 1", but getting an empty result.

case 2:-
There is some data in my elastic like region = "REGION1"

I want to get all the data where "REGION1", I am getting the exact response.

I am querying on elastic as exact field match, I am not getting why this is happening even I have made the field as not_analyzed.

Comment: What version of Elasticsearch do you use? `not_analyzed` option is deprecated in the last versions. Use `keyword` as a type of field instead.

Comment: @briarheart, elastic search dB 2.4.1 and from spring boot what it is picking default

Comment: If you are sure that Spring Data Elasticsearch is generating the right code, maybe we can leave out that indirection and you could post the docs, the relevant part of the mapping, and the query? It's a little hard to guess all the right pieces here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed all the fields to not_analyzed and wrote a term query and it worked for me.